# How to create a simple orbit animation using 3D CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm attempting to create a simple loading animation of a moon orbiting a planet.
I'm using 3d css to simulate an elliptical orbit but I can't get the animation to look how I would prefer, explained below. I feel I may have over complicated it along the way.

This is where I'm up to so far:

```css
.outer {
  width: vw;
  height: vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.planet-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(75deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.planet-outer {
  animation: planet 2s infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% -25%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.planet {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 999px;
  margin: 75% auto 0 auto;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-75deg);
}

.back-circle {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: perspective(150px) translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px);
}

@keyframes planet {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(150px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(150px) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="loading-icon">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="back-circle"></div>
      <div class="planet-container">
        <div class="planet-outer">
          <div class="planet"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And below is a quick diagram of my desired animation:

[image]

As you can see, the elliptical orbit & perspective is working well. However, the "moon" is scewed and flipping as it rotates, and is not obscured behind the "planet" on its return orbit. I understand why these aspects are not working correctly, but despite playing around for a while, I am unable to come up with a solid solution to these issues.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "simple loading animation"... what you want to do is not simple. ¿possible? maybe... but for a loader just make a gif or (better) svg animation. JMHO

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Fair enough thank you, I thought it may be simple as I'm always shocked with what people can do with 3d transforms. My first attempt was using SVG animation, but I had issue with obscuring the moon on the return orbit. I may have to use a gif but it's not my preferred solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try give the earth a z-index: 1 , and the moon z-index : 2 ; and during animation when the moon reach the edge of the earth give it a z index of 0. This will cause the moon to appear in front of the photo when he reach the end of the orbit and disappear behind the earth when he return to the beginning.

another simple trick is to play with opacity.

HTML :

```
 <div class="earth"></div>
 <div class="moon"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
  background-color: #0b132b;
}

.earth {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: fadeIn 1.7s backwards;
}

.moon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: center center;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: orbit 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit {
  from {
    transform: rotate(150deg)  translateX(70px) rotate(-140deg);
    z-index: -1;
   
   
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(504deg) translateX(70px) rotate(-500deg);
    
  }
}

}
```